# Schema of an XSD?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm looking for the Schema document on basis of which an XSD is created.
I need this because I want to transform an XML to XSD using XSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right here: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Note that your browser might not display it exactly as it is stored, so you may want to use `View Source`.

Answer (score 1):

The XSD will be based on your XSD version.

Version 1.1: http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd
Version 1.0: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Reference: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema